# CAML Query with IN + AND or other

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

My question is about caml query SP2010,
i've got colums as follow: Country, Role, Species, Species, Topic, Documenttype, Searchtext.
There is possible that user will search by Countries (multiple->UK,France,Belgium) and type document name like Doc_num_one.txt and add other criteria like Role, Species, Species, Topic, Documenttype. I've tried different queries but I think I stucked.
Below what I tried so far:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <In>
            <FieldRef Name="Country"/>
            <Values>
                <Value Type="Lookup">United Kingdom</Value>
                <Value Type="Lookup">Poland</Value>
                <Value Type="Lookup">Belgium</Value>
            </Values>
        </In>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

or

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Title" />
                <Value Type="Text">doc num two</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Country" />
                        <Value Type="Lookup">United Kingdom</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Role" />
                        <Value Type="Lookup">Super Admin</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Country" />
                        <Value Type="Lookup">Belgium</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Role" />
                        <Value Type="Lookup">Super Admin</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Country" />
                        <Value Type="Lookup">Poland</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Role" />
                        <Value Type="Lookup">Super Admin</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
            </Or>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

**Solution:**

```
<Query>
<Where>
<And>
 <In>
 <FieldRef Name="Country"/>
 <Values>
  <Value Type="Lookup">United Kingdom</Value>
  <Value Type="Lookup">Poland</Value>
  <Value Type="Lookup">Belgium</Value>
 </Values>
 </In>
<In>
 <FieldRef Name="Role"/>
 <Values>
  <Value Type="Lookup">Super Admin</Value>
  <Value Type="Lookup">Admin</Value>
  <Value Type="Lookup">User</Value>
 </Values>
 </In>
</And>
</Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: and what is the output from that query. And more  importantly what is not working ?

Comment: first one is working fine but it's possible that it's going to be 40 countries + other criteria.I mentioned in question.So I wonder how to costruct query countries(multiple) +  Title, Role, Species, Species, Topic, Documenttype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query does not work because it has more than two child elements within the `<Or>` element. If you want to test more sub-conditions, you have to introduce helper elements:

```
<Or>
    <And>...</And>
    <And>...</And>
    <And>...</And>
    <And>...</And>
    <And>...</And>
</Or>
```

becomes

```
<Or>
    <And>...</And>
    <Or>
        <And>...</And>
        <Or>
            <And>...</And>
            <Or>
                <And>...</And>
                <And>...</And>
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </Or>
</Or>
```

The same applies to `<And>` elements.

Comment: 40 different countries + text (provided by user) + Title, Role, Species, Species, Topic, Documenttype .I am trying to create query via js. How You think its going to look like?

Comment: Then you have to create even more nested `<Or>`s. For sure, it will not look very good (I added two more `<And>`s in my example). I would put all the `<And>`s into an array and write a helper function that creates the `<Or>`s.